# Maven tomcat deployment fails (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I was able to deploy my WAR file to tomcat manager using the webapp, but when I try to do it with the maven plugin (tomcat7:deploy) the upload fails after a couple of seconds (~3 megabytes) with this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy (default-cli)
> on project {project_name}: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection
> reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy
> (default-cli) on project {project_name}: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot
> invoke Tomcat manager     at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
> at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
> ... 20 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by
> peer: socket write error  at
> java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)   at
> java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
> org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:163)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:856)
> at
> org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:266)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
> at
> org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
> at
> org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:708)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:515)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:923)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:684)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:367)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
> ... 23 more

The relevant bit of the POM is as follows:

```
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
```

With TomcatServer defined in maven conf/settings.xml as:

```
    <server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
```

What might be causing the connection to reset? I increased the timeouts in conf/server.xml, which didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven settings preferences were pointed to the wrong location (they can be changed in eclipse: window -> preferences -> maven -> User Settings). Mine defaulted to /.m2/settings.xml, which didn't exist. it was also helpful to use the redeploy goal, instead of deploy, to clarify that the upload was actually failing immediately.

Comment: You can also simply change ".m2" directory with a junction to what ever destination, e.g. `mklink /J .m2 f:\java\maven`